# many to many field in django view

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, many-to-many

I try to write a view user create paper trading,I have some assets in my site,now when user create paper trading have to choose from that assets,but cant create and have an error

```
    # -------------------- Create Paper_Trading View --------------------


class CreatePaperTradingApiView(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    """
    create a paper_trading for request.user
    """
    serializer_class = PaperTradingSerializer

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=True, url_name='paper', url_path='paper')
    def create_paper_trading(self, request, pk=None):
        data = request.data

        symbol = Assets.objects.get(id=pk).core_key
        user_id = request.user.pk
        if not PaperTrading.objects.filter(user=user_id, status='OPENED').filter(assets__core_key=symbol).exists():
            queryset = PaperTrading.objects.create(

                user_id=user_id,
                average_price=data['average_price'],
                quantity=data['quantity'],
                status='OPENED',
                side=data['side']).assets.set(Assets.objects.filter(core_key=symbol))

            queryset = PaperTrading.objects.filter(user=user_id, status='OPENED').filter(assets__core_key=symbol)

            serializer = PaperTradingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(data={'result': 'This symbol opened.'})
```

I took assets from list of asset that is many to many field

The error is

"<PaperTrading: PaperTrading object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the Many to many relationship is `Assets` to `PaperTrading` (it would be good to see your models otherwise. Try:

```py
new_instance = PaperTrading.objects.create(
    user_id=user_id,
    average_price=data['average_price'],
    quantity=data['quantity'],
    status='OPENED',
    side=data['side'],
)

new_instance.assets.set(Assets.objects.filter(core_key=symbol))

...
```

My thought is that you firstly need to create the object before you assign its' M2M.